# How to use npm libraries with electron-forge

Tags: npm, electron, electron-forge

I am trying to build an Electron project that uses the walkdir library installed via npm. I have electron forge setup, but after trying to open up the zip file in the out folder, I get a message saying: Uncaught Exception: Error: Cannot find module 'walkdir'. How can I declare external libraries with electron-forge? Do I need to add a declaration to the package.json?

Answer (score 0):

I just had to npm install the packages again from inside my src directory and ensure that they were in my package.json as dependencies